# What does the boolean in this context do?

Tags: python, boolean

What does the boolean in this context do?
What does true represent?
This is python idle v3.4.2
The code works, i am just unsure how it functions

```
ans=True
while ans:
    print("""
    1.Take the quiz
    2.View and sort scores
    3.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans=input("What would you like to do? ")
    if ans=="1":
      print("\n Taking quiz")
      quiz()
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting an initial `ans` to `True`, it satisfies the `while ans` loop for the first time. If it were a falsy value, the loop wouldn't ever be entered. (Of course, if the variable didn't exist at all, there would be a `NameError`)

`ans` is then updated each time you type an input (presumed `"1"`, `"2"`, or `"3"`). This loop keeps going until you've typed "1", in which case it takes the quiz.

If you press enter without typing anything, ans becomes an empty string `""`. The `while ans` is no longer satisfied and you break out of the loop, either continuing with whatever code is next or terminating the program.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, they are using `ans` as a check to see if they should continue to loop. They originally set it to `True` so that the loop will execute the first time.

All further executions of the loop will be dependent on what `ans` is set to afterwards, but it doesn't actually seem like they want it to loop by the way that small snippet of code is written.